# How to loop through files sorted by modified date with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have gazillion files in a folder, they have been uploaded there every 30 minutes for a few years now.

I have a macro to open and modify files with or after specified last modified date, however it checks every file in the folder to determine if it satisfies the condition or not which takes forever.

Is there a way to first sort files in descending order by modified date and set macro to go from the top and just break once a specified date is reached?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not move the older files into a subfolder ?

Comment: Because that requires manual intervention on the files - there is a pressure to avoid that :-} Alternatively I could move the newest ones into temp folder. The idea though is that finally the macro would run automatically at the specified times during the day, so user intervention is avoided.

Comment: If your macro moves the older files then after the first run you're only processing a small number of files every run.  No manual steps.

Comment: I cannot move the files anywhere as it is a shared folder which is used by various counterparties. I could only move new ones temporarily to other folder and run macro there. However new files arrive every 30 minutes so that would be a pain to do it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep all the files in one folder then something like this might be faster: you only need to check the modified date until you reach the first "too old" file.

```vb
Sub tester()
    Const FOLDER As String = "C:\Tester\"
    Dim arr, f
    arr = AllFilesNewestFirst(FOLDER & "*")
    For Each f In arr
        If Len(f) > 0 Then
            'process files until last modified is >10 days ago
            If FileDateTime(FOLDER & f) < Date - 10 Then Exit For
            
            'process this file
            Debug.Print "Processing: " & f
            
        End If
    Next f
End Sub


'return an array of all files matching `pattern`, using dir 
Function AllFilesNewestFirst(pattern)
    Dim s As String
    Dim oShell As Object
    Dim oExec As Object, cmd
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    cmd = "cmd /c dir """ & pattern & """ /A-D-H-S /b /o-d"
    s = oShell.Exec(cmd).StdOut.readall()
    AllFilesNewestFirst = Split(s, vbCrLf)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use [`DateLastModified`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datelastmodified-property).  If it's before/after a date, then you can run the rest of the macro:

```
Sub ShowFileAccessInfo(filespec)
    Dim fs, f, s
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(filespec)
    s = UCase(filespec) & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Created: " & f.DateCreated & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Last Accessed: " & f.DateLastAccessed & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Last Modified: " & f.DateLastModified  
    MsgBox s, 0, "File Access Info"
End Sub
```

Admittedly, it requires each file to be opened, but it would work.

Edit: Using the above, you could even create a quick function:

```
Function modified_date(filespec) As Date
    Dim fs, f, s
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(filespec)
    modified_date = Format(f.datelastmodified, "MM/DD/YYYY")
End Function

Sub t()
Dim myFile As String
myFile = "C:\User\Documents\SomeFile.pdf"

Dim oldestDate As Date
oldestDate = Format("10/1/2010", "MM/DD/YYYY")

Dim fileModifiedDate As Date
fileModifiedDate = modified_date(myFile)

Debug.Print "File was last modified on: " & filemodified; Date
Debug.Print "You want to run this on files modified after: " & oldestDate

If oldestDate <= fileModifiedDate Then
    Debug.Print "This file is modified AFTER your chosen date"
    ' Do stuff
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Bruce, thank you for the response! The issue is though that checking modified date for every file when there are thousands of files in the folder, takes a lot of time. I already have a code that works, but is too slow since it needs to check every's file modified date to determine if it is to be action on or not. Is there a workaround to check files sorted in desc order by date so it can break after having checked few files rather than to verify every one (let alone open it)? Many thanks!

Comment: Ideally, it would follow folder's settings regarding sorting as that is the fastest thing to do to sort that way :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this is going to get painful, but it should be faster once you get it working.  We'll use the DIR command of the CMD  shell and send the output to a file.

1. Use the Shell VBA command to execute CMD with a "dir /o:d /t:w **.* > mylisting.txt".  This will create a date-sorted listing of your files (oldest first) and put it in a file called mylisting.txt.
2. Wait around until the shell command finishes.  Maybe loop 10 ten times, sleeping for a few seconds and then looking for your file to be created.  Handle the error if the file doesn't show up.
3. Read the file into a new worksheet as text file.
4. Starting at the bottom of that new sheet, parse out the file name and the write date.  Regular expression functions might be useful for this.
5. Execute your file-by-file logic.
6. Loop up to the top entry until the write date < your trigger date.
7. Clean up.